# How can I arrange a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am having a hard time trying to arrange the dictionary according the following way the given number in the input which is `5` then search for `key=5` in the dictionary put it the first and then its first value `4` and search for `key=4` in the dictionary and put its value as second and then the second value of `5` which is `3` and search for `key=3` in the dictionary and put its value as third

The values will be one or two integers

I'm working in drawing a binary tree so it will be easier if the root node(parent) which is 5 here be the first and then its children, children etc next

I tried to arrange it using `OrderedDict` but i couldn't find away with it

Can someone help me please?

Input:

```
{8: [9], 3: [6, 8], 4: [2, 1], 5: [4, 3], 6: [0, 7]}
```

Output:

```
{5: [4, 3], 4: [2, 1], 3: [6, 8], 6: [0, 7], 8: [9]}
```

Updated Code:

```
def dfs(cur, prev, edges, res):
    for next in edges[cur]:
        if next == prev: continue

        res.setdefault(cur, []).append(next)

        dfs(next, cur, edges, res)


def construct_tree(edges, root):
    d = {}
    x = []
    for edge in edges:
        u, v = edge
        d.setdefault(u, []).append(v)
        d.setdefault(v, []).append(u)

    res = {}

    dfs(root, -1, d, res)

    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':

        root_node = 5
        edges = [[2, 4], [4, 1], [0, 6], [7, 6], [8, 9], [4, 5], [6, 3], [3, 5], [3, 8]]
        print((construct_tree(edges, root_node)))
```

Comment: Where is the input, i.e. the order of keys coming from? Literally from `input` or `raw_input`?

Comment: i want to arrange it according to the root node(key) in the dictionary, first the root node = 5 first and then the values of the root node and search for it in the dictionary's keys and put it next

Comment: and again until the end and if the value number is not there in the dictionary key continue

Comment: OrderedDict isn't really good for anything unless you want to remember the order things were _added_ to the dict. Dicts, as unordered collections, are pretty terrible at keeping things in order in general. You're probably better off using a different data structure like a list of lists. What you lose in access times you will make up for in not having to constantly sort and resort.

Comment: `dict`s are completely ordered. `OrderedDict` maintain the order in which the keys were inserted; you can't arbitrarily order the keys, other than engineering the insertion order.

Comment: also, why do you need this output? are you sure you need it?

Comment: I guess you could create and recreate OrderedDicts until you get it right. Depends what you're doing where your costs start to hurt. Really it seems like your problems are that you're using an unordered collection as a go-between for ordered input and ordered output

Comment: the order of keys are coming from an unsorted edge list that are given from as an input with the root node of the binary tree, i updated my code for arranging the edge list into a dictionary please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of an interesting question, because it's subtly more complicated than you'd think. This dips into path finding, so things like depth-first and breadth-first searches are important to think about.

From your sample in/out, it looks like you want a breadth-first search, so we'll need a queue to work out of. Of course you'll also need an OrderedDict to put your nodes as you find and populate them, and your sample data.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from queue import Queue

sample_dict = {8: [9], 3: [6, 8], 4: [2, 1], 5: [4, 3], 6: [0, 7]}
```

You're given the first node from somewhere, so just call that an argument to the function, go grab each item in that key's value, and add it to the queue, then push through the queue until you're done!

```
def sort_the_dict(in_, firstkey):
    # in_ is your sample data.
    result_dict = OrderedDict()
    q = Queue()
    q.put_nowait(firstkey)

    while not q.empty():
        k = q.get_nowait():
        v = in_.get(k)
        if v is not None:
            # if a value exists for that key
            result_dict[k] = v
            for vv in v:
                q.put_nowait(vv)

    return result_dict
```

Comment: I'm getting an error  here     v = k.get(in_, k)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Joe yeah I had a brain fart there. I've already fixed it. Should be `in_.get(k)`

Comment: kindly can you look to my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295005/coordinates-of-binary-tree if its possible please check it @adam-smith

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {8: [9], 3: [6, 8], 4: [2, 1], 5: [4, 3], 6: [0, 7]}

sorted_keys = sorted([x for x in d])
sorted_d = OrderedDict(zip(sorted_keys, [d[k] for k in sorted_keys]))
```

Instead of sorting numerically, you can replace `sorted_keys` with however you want to sort the dict. This is how you can accomplish what you're asking, but I would echo the other comments and say that there's probably a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.